# Show that $e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$ using the Fourier Series only

Tags: real-analysis, integration, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, trigonometric-series

As stated in the title.

Any arbitrary function can be expressed as
$$f(x)=\frac{a_0}{2}+\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}(a_n\cos(nx)+b_n\sin(nx)) \tag{1}$$
where
$$a_n=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)\cos(nx)dx \tag{2}$$
$$b_n=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)\sin(nx)dx \tag{3}$$

---

I am trying to show that (1)-(3) are consistent with $f(x)=e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$.

However, for $a_n=\frac{1}{\pi}\int^{\pi}_{-\pi}e^{ix}\cos(nx)dx$ I got $a_n=0$, similarly, $b_n=0$.

What's gone wrong? Are the integral limits $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}$ not valid in general, does it require modifications for non-periodic functions?

Comment: Use `\cos x` and `\sin x` etc for trig and similar functions.

Comment: Most likely you made a mistake when computing $a_n$. For example, I get $a_1 = 1$.

Comment: First, you need a definition of $e^{ix}$.  Next there are interesting questions like this:  Can we evaluate $$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{ix}\cos(5x)dx$$without using $e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$?  Presumably, giving this integral to Mathematica or Maple will not be allowed since those programs may, in fact, use $e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$ when they do it.

Comment: Your equation (1) will hold only on the interval $-\pi < x < \pi$.  But if $f(x)$ has period $2\pi$, it will also hold for the rest of the real line.

Comment: @GEdgar The way I read the question is that he only wants to verify that you indeed get what is expected (and I think he just made an error in the computation). Whether this is circular reasoning, is a different question.

Comment: @Klaus I did it by integration by parts but I keep getting zeros (n=integer), (also checked the integrals with Wolfram), could you show me how you did it?

Comment: Hah this is a clever problem. Fairly overkill, but I'm amused. Presumably the definition of complex exponential used here is the derivative property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try this definition: $f(x) = e^{ix}$ is the unique differentiable function $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb C$ that satisfies
$$
f'(x) = if(x),\qquad f(0)=1.
\tag4$$
Then let's try to evaluate the required integrals $(2),(3)$ using integration by parts.
*We will do this only using $(4)$.  No complex exponentials appear in what I do below, so I will not accidentally use other properties of $e^{ix}$*

Start with $(2)$, integrate by parts, use $(4)$ on the result.  We get
$$
a_n = \frac{-i}{n}\;b_n
\tag5$$
Start with $(3)$ in the same way.  We get
$$
b_n = \frac{i}{n}\;a_n + \frac{(-1)^n}{\pi n}(f(-\pi)-f(\pi))
\tag6$$
Solving the system $(5),(6)$, we get (in case $n \ne 1$)
$$
a_n = \frac{i n (-1)^n}{\pi(n^2-1)}\;(f(\pi)-f(-\pi))
\\
b_n = \frac{n(-1)^n}{\pi(n^2-1)}\;(f(-\pi)-f(\pi))
$$

Unless we can prove $f(\pi) = f(-\pi)$ from the definition $(4)$, it seems we will not be able to complete this.

Now consider $n=1$.  We get equations
$$
b_1 = ia_1
\\
a_1 = a_1 +\frac{i}{\pi}\;(f(\pi)-f(-\pi))
$$
so we conclude $f(\pi)-f(-\pi) = 0$.  This tells us $a_n = b_n = 0$ for $n \ne 1$.  Write $A = a_1$.  Putting this all into $(1)$ we have
$$
f(x) = A\big(\cos(x) + i\sin(x)\big)
\tag7$$
Finally, we evaluate the constant $A$.  For that we use $f(0)=1$
in $(7)$ to get $A=1$.

Comment: Professor, I am still getting zero everywhere. I ended up with something like $a_n=\frac{1}{n}[\frac{i}{n}(0+cos(n\pi)e^{i\pi}-cos(n\pi)e^{i\pi})+\frac{\pi}{n}a_n] \to a_n=0$ for $n \subset Z$ etc

Comment: Note, you should have both $e^{i\pi}$ and $e^{-i\pi}$ in your formula.  I will check the case $n=1$ in my method, that is the case it should be nonzero.

Answer (score 2):

If you allow for complex coefficients, then the Fourier-series of $x\mapsto \cos (x) + \mathrm i \sin(x)$ is just itself (by uniqueness of the Fourier-series).
You can formally compute the Fourier-coefficients of $x\mapsto \mathrm e^{\mathrm i x}$ using integration by parts twice and you obtain (for $k>1$)
$$
a_k = -\frac{2k \sin(k \pi)}{\pi(k^2-1)}=0,
$$
since $k\in\mathbb N$ and $a_0 = 0$ and $a_1 = 1$. The completely similar computation (again for $k>1$) shows
$$
b_k = -\frac{2\mathrm i \sin(k\pi)}{\pi(k^2-1)}=0
$$
and $b_0=0$ and $b_1 =\mathrm i$. Therefore the Forier-series of the two functions agree and they are therefore the same.

EDIT: GEdgar made a very valid point. In order to evaluate the integrals, one can use the ODE she or he had given as mentioned in the comments but one gets another proof of the identity along the way. So I propose another way of doing it:

We use that $f(x) = \mathrm e^{\mathrm i x}$ satisfies the ODE $f' = \mathrm i f$ with the initial datum $f(0)=1$. If $f$ has the Fourier-series
$$
f(x) = \frac{a_0}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_n\cos(nx) + b_n\sin(nx))
$$
you can take a formal derivative and see that
$$
f'(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-na_n\sin(nx) + nb_n\cos(nx))
$$
Using the ODE above you get $a_0=0$ and the relations (for $n>0$): $- n a_n = \mathrm ib_n$ and $nb_n = \mathrm i a_n$.
From there you get $\mathrm i n^2b_n=\mathrm i b_n$ and therefore $b_n=0$ for $n>1$. Similarly you get $a_n=0$ for $n>1$. If $n=1$ one finds $-a_1=\mathrm ib_1$ and $b_1 = \mathrm i a_1$. But now we know that $f(0) =a_1 = 1$ and therefore $b_1 = \mathrm i$.

Comment: Perhaps you evaluation of $a_k, b_k$ has used $e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$ ??

Comment: I see what you mean but you can circumvent in the following way starting from your ODE: If you translate $f'(x) = \mathrm i f(x)$, $f(0)=1$ into $\mathbb R^2$, you represent $f = a + \mathrm ib$ by a vector $(a,b)$ and the ODE reads $(a'b') = (b,-a)$ from which you obtain by differentiating again $a'' = -a$ and $b''=-b$. With your initial condition you get $a=\cos(x)$ and $b(x) = \sin(x)$ and therefore you can evaluate $a$ and $b$ in $\pm \pi$ which you need in order to compute the integrals. But along the way you get of course a new proof of Euler's identity.

Comment: I edited my answer in order to include another way of looking at the problem.